# php Mongodb driver query class

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having a list of `_id` and want to write a query to retrieve all documents matching the `_id`s in one single query.

Can someone help me out there?

```
$filter = ['_id' => 1];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
```

How should `$filter` be written to retrieve all documents with an `_id` in array.

Comment: You want to use IN like we use in Mysql Right ?

Comment: You have to you use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

Comment: Show your array of _id

Comment: Array ( [0] => 401550 [1] => 75908070 [2] => 75907788 [3] => 75905824 [4] => 87478311 [5] => 75907342 [6] => 75906100 [7] => 75904838 [8] => 85748056 [9] => 85070878 [10] => 85070914 [11] => 80395572 [12] => 88154 [13] => 95038204 [14] => 95613660 [15] => 95545447 [16] => 95039333 [17] => 95038781 [18] => 85075632 [19] => 95322093 [20] => 83128959 [21] => 6552000 [22] => 6524152 [23] => 84651298 [24] => 90451239 [25] => 94450954 [26] => 92112433 [27] => 90445776 [28] => 90445609 [29] => 93412721 [30] => 92118926 [31] => 6552032 [32] => 90449841 [33] => 304704 [34] => 92119164 [35] => 90449313)

Comment: i am having above array and these are _id's,

Comment: `$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['_id' => ['$in' => $idArray]]);`

Comment: thanks even i figured it out, working perfectly fine.